# Gwd custom components and event handlers for it

Tags: javascript, json

i wanted to know if its possible to build a custom component for gwd and add an predefined event to it.

My use case is as follows.

1. build a custom component
2. onclick/ontouch - handler1 called.
3. onmouseover - handler2 called.

For 2 and 3 , will depend which event the user chooses in gwd tool.

I tried searching but couldn't find any info other than this

http://html5advertising.de/2015/08/spritesheets-how-to-create-a-custom-gwd-component/

Let me know if its possible to add predefined event and how can i proceed with it.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it is possible to build your own custom component,
here is the documentation for reference.

- https://support.google.com/webdesigner/topic/6175711?hl=en

Also here is the documentation if you need to know more about the pre-installed components

- https://support.google.com/webdesigner/topic/3181232?hl=en&ref_topic=3227692&vid=1-635757671172469129-3504227944

Let me know if you need more information